# BMC Remedy ticket status change error in asp net

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, remedy

I'm using MVC to manage the BMC ticket raise and resolve. However for certain groups there are additional fields that opens up after choosing the type of change as 'Resolved'
I tried input values to those fields but still I'm not able to resolve the incident.
Below is the code used,

```
StagingRequest.Incident_Nature = "NA";
StagingRequest.Network_Infrastructure = "NA";
StagingRequest.Incident_Element = "NA";
String ss = _WS1.HelpDesk_Modify(_AI1, StagingRequest.Incident_Number, StagingRequest.Type_of_Change, StagingRequest.Status_Reason, StagingRequest.Group_Name, StagingRequest.Assignee_Login_ID, StagingRequest.Resolution, StagingRequest.Incident_Nature, StagingRequest.Network_Infrastructure, StagingRequest.Incident_Element, StagingRequest.WorkLog_SupportDiary, StagingRequest.Work_Info_Notes, StagingRequest.Expiry_Date);
```

Note that I tried entering the actual dropdown values in those 3 fields still the same error

> Unable to Modify :ERROR (100000308): ; Please choose the value for the following fields before resolving the ticket; 'Incident Nature', 'Network Infrastructure' and 'Incident Element'.

The other groups for which additional fields is not required worked with the below code,

```
String ss = _WS1.HelpDesk_Modify(_AI1, StagingRequest.Incident_Number, StagingRequest.Type_of_Change, StagingRequest.Status_Reason, StagingRequest.Group_Name, StagingRequest.Assignee_Login_ID, StagingRequest.Resolution, null, StagingRequest.Cause_for_SLA_Violation, StagingRequest.SLA_Comments, StagingRequest.WorkLog_SupportDiary, StagingRequest.Work_Info_Notes, StagingRequest.Expiry_Date);
```

Answer (score 0):

Analyze the difference in groups in Remedy. Some groups are differently customized in remedy while resolving the incidents.